# How to clone/copy files that contain in your name, reserved characters of a server to a local storage using Wget?

Tags: wget

I can not download files from a server of my work because the names of the files have reserved characters (error not controlled by the company and by the erroneous named by the clients that uploads attachments) and for some reason the 404 error even though the files exist on the server, by the way I use wget for this task.

This is the executing line that starts the download (list.txt contains url lines from the server to the file in question- example: https://example.com/files/122301/8+.pdf)

```
wget.exe -x -i "C:\clon\list.txt" -P "C:\clon\destino" -nv -o "C:\clon\log.txt"
```

I do not know the functionality of the parameters given in wget in addition to the source / destination routes such as the log but some files contain '}' or '+' in their file names and therefore (I think) the missing files are not downloaded ( I have 93% downloaded from all files)

Examples of files including these characters:

- /FC04-6198}+.pdf
- /8+.pdf
- /PT05+2236.pdf

Try placing these parameters "--content-disposition" or "--restrict-file-names" but nothing.

I expect to get a way to ignore the reserved characters to be able to download them.

Comment: When Wget does not download the file, can you show the error it displays? No matter the filename, Wget will URLEncode it and send a request, it is upon your web server to send the response

Comment: Directly I see this message "ERROR 404: Not Found." and the URLencode was like this:http://procesoscontables.bpmco.com.co/archivos/12_2018/207618/FC04_6198%7D+.pdf. Validating on the server, the file does exist.